Awesome Notifications not triggered when device is locked
the notifications are not triggered when the device is locked or app is killed,
but when I open the device then it comes
I have set the awesome notifications as follows:
import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';
Future<void> main() async {
  //debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Always initialize Awesome Notifications
  await NotificationController.initializeLocalNotifications();
  await NotificationController.initializeIsolateReceivePort();
  await Geolocator.requestPermission();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

  static List<Map<String, dynamic>> allWeeksNotifications = [
    {
      'notificationweekday': 'Sunday',
      'notificationtime': '09:00',
      'notificationtitle': 'Ssunday Notification',
      'notificationbody': 'it is Sunday',
      'pagetype': 'tab2',
      'pageindex': 2,
      'notificationid': 1030
    }]

  static Future<void> initializeLocalNotifications() async {
    await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
      null,
      [
      NotificationChannel(
        channelKey: 'adan_channel',
        channelName: 'Adan Notifications',
        channelDescription: 'Notifications for Adan prayer times',
        defaultColor: Colors.green,
        ledColor: Colors.green,
        importance: NotificationImportance.High,
        channelShowBadge: true,
      ),
    ],);

    initialAction = await AwesomeNotifications()
        .getInitialNotificationAction(removeFromActionEvents: false);
  }

here is my try

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
